# T-SQL: Find column match within a string (LIKE but different)

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

**Server**: SQL Server 2008 R2

I apologize in advance, as I'm not sure of the best way to verbalize the question. I'm receiving a string of email addresses and I need to see if, within that string, any of the addresses exist as a user already. The query that obviously doesn't work is shown below, but hopefully it helps to clarify what I'm looking for:

```
SELECT f_emailaddress
FROM tb_users
WHERE f_emailaddress LIKE '%user1@domain.com,user2@domain.com%'
```

I was hoping SQL had an "InString" operator, that would check for matches "within the string", but I my Google abilities must be weak today.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated. If there simply isn't a way, I'll have to dig in and do some work in the codebehind to split each item in the string and search on each one.

Thanks in advance,
Beems

Comment: String split is a very common function.  If you need help then I suggest you post a question for the code behind environment you use.

Comment: Read the following articles to understand what is going on in the answer - [Split strings the right way – or the next best way](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings), [Splitting Strings : A Follow-Up](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up), [Splitting Strings : Now with less T-SQL](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql) - But take note, that what you wanted to avoid (doing it in code behind) is actually the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the input string and use `IN clause`

to split the CSV to rows use this.

```
SELECT Ltrim(Rtrim(( Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') )))
FROM   (SELECT Cast ('<M>'
                     + Replace('user1@domain.com,user2@domain.com', ',', '</M><M>')
                     + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data) AS A
       CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
```

Now use the above query in where clause.

```
SELECT f_emailaddress
FROM   tb_users
WHERE  f_emailaddress IN(SELECT Ltrim(Rtrim(( Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') )))
                         FROM   (SELECT Cast ('<M>'
                                              + Replace('user1@domain.com,user2@domain.com', ',', '</M><M>')
                                              + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data) AS A
                                CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a))
```

Or use can use `Inner Join`

```
SELECT f_emailaddress
FROM   tb_users A
       JOIN (SELECT Ltrim(Rtrim(( Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') )))
             FROM   (SELECT Cast ('<M>'
                                  + Replace('user1@domain.com,user2@domain.com', ',', '</M><M>')
                                  + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data) AS A
                    CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)) B
         ON a.f_emailaddress = b.f_emailaddress
```

Comment: Well, I'm not yet sure "how" this works, but it does, so thank you. Sincerely, thank you. I'll peel this apart and do some reading so I can understand it.

Comment: @Beems This link may help you http://oops-solution.blogspot.in/2011/10/sql-serverhow-to-split-comma-delimited.html

Answer (score 1):

You first need to split the CSV list into a temp table and then use that to `INNER JOIN` with your existing table, as that will act as a filter.

You cannot use [CONTAINS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) unless you have created a Full Text index on that table and column, which I doubt is the case here.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE #EmailAddresses (Email NVARCHAR(500) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO #EmailAddress (Email)
   SELECT split.Val
   FROM   dbo.Splitter(@IncomingListOfEmailAddresses);

SELECT usr.f_emailaddress
FROM tb_users usr
INNER JOIN #EmailAddresses tmp
        ON tmp.Email = usr.f_emailaddress;
```

Please note that the reference to "dbo.Splitter" is a placeholder for whatever string splitter you already have or might get. Please do *not* use any splitter that makes use of a `WHILE` loop. The best options are either the SQLCLR- or XML- based ones. The XML-based ones are generally fast but do have some issues with encoding if the string to be split has special XML characters such as `&`, `<`, or `"`. If you want a quick and easy SQLCLR-based splitter, you can download the Free version of the [SQL#](http://www.SQLsharp.com/) library (which I am the creator of, but this feature is in the free version) which contains `String_Split` and `String_Split4k` (for when the input is always <= 4000 characters).

Answer (score 0):

SQL has a `CONTAINS` and an `IN` function. You can use either of those to accomplish your task. Click on either for more information via MSDNs website! Hope this helps.

[CONTAINS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx)

`CONTAINS` will look to see if any values in your data contain the entire string you provided. Kind of similar in presentations to `LIKE '%myValue%';`

```
SELECT f_emailaddress
FROM tb_users
WHERE CONTAINS (f_emailaddress, 'user1@domain.com');
```

[IN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx)

`IN` will return matches for any values in the provided comma delimited list. They need to be exact matches however. You can't provide partial terms.

```
SELECT f_emailaddress
FROM tb_users
WHERE f_emailaddress IN ('user1@domain.com','user2@domain.com')
```

As far as splitting each of the values out into separate strings, have a look at the StackOverflow question found [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x). This might point you in the proper direction.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It looks like both of those are going to force me to split the string from the format in which it is received. Unfortunately, I receive it like the following:

    "user1@domain.com,user2@domain.com"

To do either CONTAINS or IN, it looks like I will need to split it. I can do it, I was just hoping for an easier solution. No big deal I guess, I'll adapt.

Comment: @Beems Okay, have a look at this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x

Comment: So, for example, the CONTAINS query gives me an error:
SELECT f_emailaddress
FROM tb_users
WHERE CONTAINS (f_emailaddress, 'user1@domain.com,user2@domain.com');

ERROR: "Syntax error near ',' in the full-text search condition"

Comment: @Beems and Volearix: `CONTAINS` only works on full-text indexed columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this(not tested).

Before using this, make sure that you have created a Full Text index on that table and column.

Replace your comma with AND then

```
SELECT id,email
FROM t
where CONTAINS(email, 'user1@domain.com and user2@domain.com');
```

Comment: @srutzky Thanks for telling me. I know that.

Comment: @Piyush If you know this, and it is relevant to the answer it is probably a good idea to include it in your answer. As you are giving this as the solution to a problem it is very likely the person that has asked the question does not know this, people very rarely criticise an answer for containing too much detail!

Comment: @srutzky and GarethD:- added in answer

Answer (score 0):

```
--prepare temp table for testing
DECLARE @tb_users AS TABLE
    (f_emailaddress VARCHAR(100))
INSERT  INTO @tb_users
        ( f_emailaddress)
VALUES  ( 'user1@domain.com' ),
        ( 'user2@domain.com' ),
        ( 'user3@domain.com' ),
        ( 'user4@domain.com' )
--Your query
SELECT  f_emailaddress
FROM    @tb_users
WHERE   'user1@domain.com,user2@domain.com' LIKE '%' + f_emailaddress + '%'
```